# Python Beginner Input and different choise

Tags: python

Though there is probably an easier way to do it, but I wish to understand what is wrong.The code should tell you the real identity of a superhero when given the superhero's name.

Here is the problem:

After you provide the superhero's real name, it would ask "Do you need more information?"; How do you setup a choice for this question?

```
super_heros = {'Hulk': 'Bruce Banner',
               'Capitan America': 'Steve Rogers',
               'Spiderman': 'Peter Parker'}
hero_biography = {'Bruce Banner' : 'David Banner nasce in California...ecc'}

while True:
    choice = input('Nome Supereroe:') ###Superhero's name:
    if choice == 'Hulk':
        print(super_heros['Hulk'])
    elif choice == 'Bruce Banner':
        choice = input('Desideri maggiori informazioni?') ###Do you want more information
    elif choice == 'Yes': ### I know that this one will refer to : choice = input('Nome Supereroe:')
        print(hero_biography['Bruce Banner'])
    elif choice == 'Capitan America':
        print(super_heros['Capitan America'])
    elif choice == 'Spiderman':
        print(super_heros['Spiderman'])
    elif choice == 'Esc':
        break
    else:
        choice == ''
        print('Nome inesistente')
```

Comment: What you need to understand is that once your `if else` block finds a correspondence, i.e., the first condition in the block is verified, it will skip the remaining `elif`'s and the loop will step to the next iteration.

Comment: You do not need the if statements. Just do `print(super_heroes[choice])` I would use it within a try statement in order to catch an exception if the key does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested condition with another variable, e.g. choice2

```
...
elif choice == 'Bruce Banner':
    choice2 = input('Desideri maggiori informazioni?')
    if choice2 == "Yes":
        print(hero_biography['Bruce Banner'])
elif choice == 'Captain America':
...
```

Comment: I've already tried to do it, but when I run it, I get this message: Name 'choice2' can be not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use "elif" instead of a nested "if" to check, if the second choice is "Yes".

It would be helpful if you split your code into smaller chunks (functions). Then you may write your code like this:

```
choice = input('Nome Supereroe:')
while choice != 'Esc':
    printCharacterInfo(choice)
    choice = input('Nome Supereroe:')

def printCharacterInfo(character):
    try:
        print(super_heros[character])
    except KeyError:
        if character in hero_biography:
            proposeBiographyInformation(character)

        else:
            print('Nome inesistente')

def proposeBiographyInformation(name):
    if input('Desideri maggiori informazioni?') == 'Yes':
        print(hero_biography[name])
```

Comment: You only ask to show more information if a user entered a wrong hero name. This looks wrong.

Comment: The question says: _I want to insert a line, that allows to get more information about the superhero, if you put in it **the real name**_ - I assumed intersection real name and Superhero name sets is an empty set.

Comment: You are right, i missunderstood the question. The way u use the try catch block still looks... interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try it this way:

```
while True:
    choice = input('Nome Supereroe:')

    if choise in super_heros:
        print(super_heros[choise])

    elif choise in hero_biography:
        moreInformation = input('Desideri maggiori informazioni?')
        if moreInformation == 'yes':
            print(hero_biography[choise])

    else:
        print('Nome inesistente')
```

Answer (score 0):

If any of your elif condition is satisfied it will not check the next elif condition.
If your input :
Nome Supereroe:Bruce Banner
It satisfies elif choice == 'Bruce Banner': condition and your input here is 
Desideri maggiori informazioni?Yes
I will not check elif choice == 'Yes': condition as it has already satisfied your previous condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the input function again and assign to different variable, it will not affect the original input.  You can ask for this just where if block ends, i.e. below else.  For example..

```
...
else:
        choice == ''
        print('Nome inesistente')

newChoice = input('Do you need more information?')
#your code to handle new choice user entered.
```